# How do you reset a persistent Windows 11 account lock out?

Tags: windows-11, password-recovery

My father's managed to stuff up his Windows 11 laptop by entering the wrong password too many times. Googling around, it seems he's not the only one. It's now insisting on a challenge phrase "A1B2C3" on every boot. That's fine, he can get past that. But then it asks for his "PIN". (Strange, but it's always asked for his alphanumeric password as a "PIN". In reality I'm sure this his laptop password, not a Windows Hello PIN as he's never set the latter up.)

Even though we're sure he's now got the right password, he then gets an error: "This sign in option is disabled because of failed sign-in attempts or repeated shutdowns. Use a different sign-in option or keep your device powered on for at least 2 hours and then try again."

[image: Sign in option disabled]

Sadly, he's not got any other sign-in options available. So waiting seems the obvious option. But having waited two hours then 24 hour to be sure, we've seen no change. It's pretty borked. The initial cause might have been a duff password, but something is seriously wrong with the timeout reset.

I think I might be on a hiding to reinstallation, but want to explore all options first:

**Forgotten password reset**

I believe he's using an profile linked to his online Microsoft-attached account rather than a local one, but there's no option to reset one's "PIN" like I get on my own Windows 10 machine:

[image: Forgot PIN and sign-in options]

**Reset from admin account**

There's no admin account set up on the machine, and despite attempts to create one from the recovery console, I'm not in the right context to use `net user` on the host system. Attempts to get to a command prompt in the right context from Safe Mode fail as that also hits the account lockout.

Ditto for changing the Local Security Policy.

**Registry hacking**

I started looking into modifying the registry to kill the lockout but don't know where to look.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RemoteAccess\Parameters\AccountLockout` looked [promising](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/editing-account-lockout-policy-via-the-registry/2a9695a8-7000-46b7-a444-5f85eecd4d20) but that's for remote not local access.

I can't believe it's this hard to reset a password/lockout with physical access available.

**utilman.exe**

My next step is to try the [utilman.exe approach](https://www.anoopcnair.com/best-methods-to-reset-windows-11-password-admin/) but I'm not hopeful as Microsoft seem to have locked down each other way too much.

There must be a simpler way to defrig this in person that doesn't involve reinstalling Windows.

Comment: We would need to see the properties of the account in question, it’s probably just locked, you can use the built-in Administrator account to provide a screenshot of the account properties.

Answer (score 2):

**(A)** It is a Microsoft Account, so then go to Microsoft Live Login and see if you / he can log in.

[Microsoft Live Login](https://account.microsoft.com/account/manage-my-account)

**(B)** If not try contacting Microsoft Support to see if he can regain access.

**(C)** If not then reinstalling Windows and setting up again is probably the only way.

If you reinstall, make a Microsoft Account (these are safe and good), a PIN, a Password and make useful records of both items.

Answer (score 1):

My temporary 'solution' (so far) to this is to enable the Admin account via the utilman.exe approach:

1. From the login screen, shift-click reboot -> troubleshooting -> advanced -> Command Prompt (recovery context)
2. `copy c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe c:\`
3. `copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe`
4. Restart
5. Click on the Accessibility icon to open command prompt (live system context)
6. `net user "Administrator" /active:yes`
7. Restart, log in as Admin.
8. Set Admin password to make account secure.

At this point I was hoping to clear the timeout or reset the password, but neither seems easy as the Home edition doesn't support the fully-fledged Local Users and Groups Computer Management snap-in, which would presumably show suitable properties for the account. `net user` doesn't seem to offer much helpful either.

[image: Broken snap-in]

Interim fix is to create a new account via `net user newaccount password /add`